# Is it possible to connect to Progress DB if you don't know any login info?

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I need to add a new account to access a progress DB, but do not have any working login details.

I have no experience with Progress only SSMS, but believe I have found the right options (Data administration > Database > Connect), added the username and password under the additional options and received **"error code 13 (316)"**. Which I'm pretty sure means it's not authorized to access the DB.
Does progress use domain accounts or only local ones? Supposedly this account runs from an app to access the data, so must have some level of permissions, but possibly read-only?

Is there any method to regain access if we don't have the right username and password for an admin to access?
I think it's possible to edit/add accounts under the 'admin' option in Data Administation however this is greyed out.
I did find Proenv which seems to be a command prompt, but can't find out what I might need to type.

I might need an ELI5 explaination on what steps I can take here (if any).

Comment: "error code 13 (316)" is just a fragment of an error message. The remainder of the message may contain relevant clues. You should post the entire error message. You should also indicate what version of OpenEdge you are using as the restrictions around access vary over time.